# I want to connect rain shower head - how should I disconnect this plug?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I had a renovation of my bathroom done recently by a contractor. Only thing he left not done was installing rain shower head (as it was still in transit from the e-store). He left me with this plug in water outlet - can I safely unscrew it and screw my rain shower in? Should I isolate it somehow so that water won't drip under the tiles? I am a total newbie when it comes to any home-improvement related things, I tried googling it but didn't find definite answer. Thank you for patience and being understanding :)

[image: the plug]

My rain shower ending
[image: rain shower ending]

Comment: hold the shower head up to the pipe and look at what it will look like when it is attached .... do you see any problems?

Comment: I think you need to get the contractor back to put this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a brass or copper block above your ceiling that the piece you're trying to remove is threaded in to. Your picture is showing what appears to be an extended plug. That's not uncommon to see after a plumber roughs in a home. The entire "plug", brass and PVC, should come out and then you'll wrap the threads of your rain head with teflon tape and thread it into the brass/copper block in the ceiling.